# Ionic 3 - Extract the side menu in it's own component

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I need to build a scalable menu for an ionic 2/3 app (preferably using ion-menu). Following the guides on the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/menu/Menu/) the menu should be a sibling of the main content and they suggest to keep it inside app.html, which is a very high place inside the app that doesn't have to be crowded too much.

If we have a big menu or if we need to use several different menus, triggered by actions inside app, this place is not appropriate for this purpose.

I want to hide the complexity of the menu in it's own container/component and handle the logic outside app.component.ts.

app.html should stay slim and a construction like the one below may be useful.

```
<app-menu></app-menu> // this should be the enclosing container of the menu logic
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

If I do this, the following error comes up:

```
Menu: must have a [content] element to listen for drag events on. Example:
<ion-menu [content]="content"></ion-menu>
<ion-nav #content></ion-nav>
```

Any thoughts on how to implement this, avoiding to add code directly to app.html and app.component.ts?

Tks

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at this [github repo](https://github.com/sebaferreras/Ionic2-MultiLevelSideMenu). If I understand your question, I did something similar there...

Answer (score 0):

error code just tells you to write `<ion-nav #content></ion-nav>` if you use `<ion-menu [content]="content"></ion-menu>`...

example toggle menu code below ...

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="danger">
      <ion-buttons start>
        <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
          <ion-icon name="menu">

          </ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>


<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-content padding>
        this is awkmal
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>


</ion-header>
<ion-nav #content></ion-nav>
```